# How to set zoom out property in google map generated script?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have generated a script using maps.google.com site, it is showing my required location but the map overlay goes out of my defined screen.

any one guide me how to zoom out 1-2 steps & bring that map overlay inside the screen to look it batter.

Example of the problem:
212.124.100.44/andrida/location/

Code:

```
<iframe width="390" height="380" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=51+Bellingham+Road,+Arthurs+Seat,+Victoria+3936,+Australia&amp;aq=&amp;sll=-38.367965,144.97331&amp;sspn=0.010077,0.01929&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=51+Bellingham+Rd,+Arthurs+Seat+Victoria+3936,+Australia&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-38.367965,144.97331&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=51+Bellingham+Road,+Arthurs+Seat,+Victoria+3936,+Australia&amp;aq=&amp;sll=-38.367965,144.97331&amp;sspn=0.010077,0.01929&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=51+Bellingham+Rd,+Arthurs+Seat+Victoria+3936,+Australia&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=-38.367965,144.97331" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see a link to customise your map before embedding. If you are not sure, follow these steps:

1) maps.google.com
2) Search the location you want to embed
3) Click on "Link" button, next to print button
4) You should now be able to see a popup next to Link button
5) Click on "Customize and preview embedded map"
6) Add you desired width, height, zoom out or even reposition the location so that the address overlay is visible.
7) If everything looks fine, just copy the embed code